# What security implication to use anyLinks: true with jQuery-terminal?

Tags: security, xss, jquery-terminal

I can't use anymore relative link in *jquery-terminal* because all links must have either a ftp or http(s) protocol.

I don't quite understand the warning https://terminal.jcubic.pl/api_reference.php#security

What could happen if I use `anyLinks: true` option to continue to use relative link ?

Comment: I can fix issue with relative links, I've just whitelisted ftp and http didn't though about urls without domain.

Comment: I've updated the code on devel branch and it now accept urls that starts with: `./` `../` and `/` but if you want to link to file in same directory you need to put `./` in front.

Comment: ok. I'll wait for the next stable anyway, because, from what you said below, I don't echo back data typed by user. just an url I make with my own data.

Comment: I've just released version 2.0 because I've needed to add one breaking change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't echo back stuff from user and don't send that to other users like with chat application or when you don't echo from users and exec commands (using execHash option) there are no security implications.

If you does echo stuff from user, then the user can put `[[!;;;;javascript:alert("xss")]xss]`, if you also allow formatting from user.
So you will be safe if you use this:

```
$('body').terminal(function(text) {
   this.echo($.terminal.escape_brackets(text));
});
```

and you'll also be safe.

And if you need to echo stuff from users and allow formatting then you need to validate user input like in normal XSS prevention but strings will be different.